# Remove stopwords-like words in a column

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, gensim, stop-words

I have a dataframe with an object column and over 100,000 rows like so:

```
    df['words']
 0 the
 1 to
 2 of
 3 a
 4 with
 5 as
 6 job
 7 mobil
 8 market
 9 think
 10....
```

Desired Output with no stopwords:

```
   df['words']
 0 way
 1 http
 2 internet
 3 car
 4 do
 5 want
 6 work
 7 uber
 8....
```

Is there a way to use gensim, spacy, or nltk to go through the usual stopwords in a single column?

I've tried:

```
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import remove_stopwords
stopwords.words('english')

df['words'] = df['words'].apply(lambda x: gensim.parsing.preprocessing.remove_stopwords(" ".join(x)))
```

But that results in:

```
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

Comment: What type is`x`?

Comment: Object but changed to string. Original Columbia object type.

Comment: You can only join lists and iterables. You need to convert to a list first

Comment: I was able to remove stopwords by this: `stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) for word in new_words: if word not in stop_wordss: print(word)` How do place back into new column in df? @mousetail

Answer (score 0):

Use nltk to rid the stop words.
import the packages

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

create the stopword list

```
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
stop_words[:10]
```

then,

```
df['newword'] = list(map(lambda line: list(filter(lambda word: word not in stop_words, line)), df.words))
df
```

Comment: Running: `df['words'].to_list()`

`stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
df['words'] = df_freq['words'].apply(lambda x: [word for word in x.split() if word not in stop_words])`
Gives `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'` error.